# How call PUT through Jersy REST client with null entity

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I want to call some "upgrade" REST API through Jersy client, which is declared as PUT and does not require any body content.

But when I request this API as below:

```
webTarget.request().put(Entity.json(null));
```

It gives error as below:

```
Entity must not be null for http method PUT.
```

So need to know, is there any way in jersy client to call PUT method with null Entity.

Answer (score 14):

You can configure the client property

> **[`SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientProperties.html#SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION)**
>
> By default, Jersey client runtime performs certain HTTP compliance checks (such as which HTTP methods can facilitate non-empty request entities etc.) in order to fail fast with an exception when user tries to establish a communication non-compliant with HTTP specification. Users who need to override these compliance checks and avoid the exceptions being thrown by Jersey client runtime for some reason, can set this property to true. As a result, the compliance issues will be merely reported in a log and no exceptions will be thrown.
>
> [...]

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.property(ClientProperties.SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION, true);
WebTarget target = client.target("...");
Response response = target.request().put(Entity.json(null));
```

Comment: It seems insecure & not robust, as my API will be public. so is there more alternate solution rather than this ?

Comment: It can be configured per request on the WebTarget (if you are reusing the Client). That's the only thing I can think that might give you some more safety

Comment: Can anybody tell me the way or a property for RESTEasy?

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same error, and solved it by using an **empty text entity**:

```
Entity<?> empty = Entity.text("");
webTarget.request().put(empty);
```

Comment: I personally think this is the cleaner solution than disabling the validation. Who knows what other things are then not checked anymore...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `webTarget.request().put(Entity.json(""));` 
It works for me.

Comment: This adds an empty JSON string as body: `""`, which is not the same as "no body"